# sharing folders over lan using python

Tags: python, file-sharing

I wanted to make an application that can allow sharing of folders between two computers connected to the same local network. I am using python to communicate between a client and server. Can anyone tell me how can i transfer a file across the network?

Comment: "I'm making an application. Can someone make it for me?"

Answer (score 2):

A very easy solution for filesharing would be to start a python webserver in the directory you'd like to share:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

But if you want "real" folder sharing, look for windows shares, samba, nfs or something alike.